# Fast in string search

Tags: c++, search

I have a problem that I am looking for some guidance to solve the most efficient way. I have 200 million strings of data ranging in size from 3 characters to 70 characters. The strings consist of letters numbers and several special characters such as dashes and underscores. I need to be able to quickly search for the entire string or any substring within a string (minimum substring size is 3). Quickly is defined here as less than 1 second.

As my first cut at this I did the following:

1. Created 38 index files. An index contains all the substrings that start with a particular letter. The first 4mb contains 1 million hash buckets (start of the hash chains). The rest of the index contains the linked list chains from the hash buckets. My hashing is very evenly distributed. The 1 million hash buckets are kept in RAM and mirrored to disk.
2. When a string is added to the index it is broken down into its non-duplicate (within itself) 3-n character substrings (when n is the length of the string-1). So, for example, "apples" is stored in the "A" index as pples,pple,ppl,pp (substrings are also stored in the "L" and "P" indexes).

The search/add server runs as a daemon (in C++) and works like a champ. Typical search times are less than 1/2 second.

The problem is on the front end of the process. I typically add 30,000 keys at a time. This part of the process takes forever. By way of benchmark, the load time into an empty index of 180,000 variable length keys is approximately 3 1/2 hours.

This scheme works except for the very long load times.

Before I go nuts optimizing (or trying to) I'm wondering is whether or not there is a better way to solve this problem. Front and back wildcard searches (ie: string like '%ppl%' in a DBMS are amazingly slow (on the order of hours in MySQL for example) for datasets this large. So it would seem that DBMS solutions are out of the question. I can't use full-text searches because we are not dealing with normal words, but strings that may or may not be composed of real words.

Comment: Unless you're to split data among machines, it does seem not a good deal to go on replicating data -- I/O is not the most performance-friendly guy.

Comment: Someone asked what data structure I was using (showed up in the Stack Exchange Icon at the top of the page), but I don't see it on this page. The data structure is described in the question. Basically a string is hashed into chained buckets.

Comment: "apples" is stored in the "A" index as pples,pple,ppl,ples,ple -- shouldn't that be "A"{pples, pple, ppl, pp}, "P"{ples,ple,pl,les,le}, "L"{es}?

Comment: Yes. I just shortened it for approximate illustration. The P and L indices would also get entries and I didn't show all the permutations in the interests of brevity. Good catch.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't even list the right "A" indexes, as far as I can tell.  Examples that are wrong are confusing.  :p

Comment: When you say "data" you mean files up to Gigabytes in size?

Comment: Some fun tweak of the trie data structure might be helpful.  With a b-tree implementation, this could be made decently efficient for lookups.

Comment: Yakk: I edited the question.

Comment: SChepurin: Yes they can become quite large.

Comment: Jaredc: The lookups are extremely fast as mentioned above. It's the creation of new keys that is slow.

Comment: @mlewis54 I attempted to fix your edit.  ples does not belong in the "A" index, because aples is not a substring of apples.

Comment: [A similar question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118759/how-to-quickly-search-through-a-very-large-list-of-strings-records-on-a-databa). Possibly useful - SQL-server [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. All the full text solutions appear to hate non-word strings. I will take a look.

Comment: I wonder if you had a 64-bit machine with enough memory if it could linearly search the entire contents with Boyer-Moore in the required time? See http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

Comment: When are the buckets "mirrored to disk"? The solution could be as simple as processing all 30k keys before writing it to disk.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads to do your initial processing?

Comment: You could take a different route and use a generalised suffix tree to hold the index. These can be built in linear time and incrementally, though you'll need enough memory to hold the entire structure in memory for good performance. It might be easier to break every string into its component 3-tuples and index these, then do the same for each search query and merge the results of searching for each 3-tuple.

Comment: @MarkRansom I initially thought of something like that but I the dataset really got to large. There might be a way to do it with multiple machines though if I go that way.

Comment: @Dukeling I am currently writing (using streams) the data when it is modified (ie, added) to the index. I would have to keep all 38 indexes in memory to do this (at a rough first guess) and then commit all the writes. This would require a multiple machine solution. I am not currently multi-threaded. That is the next phase to support multiple readers and writers.

Comment: @mlewis54, even if all 200 million strings were 70 characters, that would only be 14 gigabytes. It would certainly be cheaper to buy a single machine with that much memory than to buy multiple machines with less. You could test a representative sample of 20 million strings and see if it finishes in less than 1/10 of a second.

Comment: @MarkRansom I can test that fairly quickly.

Comment: Are the strings where you are searching static? How often do they change, ...? (Managing the whole mess can be quite a chore, and determine your data structures). Is what you searching for fixed, a fixed set of strings, ...? (Could compile the pattern to a finite automaton).

Comment: @vonbrand The strings are static. Once they are in they are never edited or deleted (delete may be come an option in the future but only if it doesn't interfere with search). The strings and substrings are fixed in the DB, but the queries can be anything.

Comment: Then you should consider a data structure like suffix lists or arrays (look around, the details are more than a bit fuzzy in my brain now). Look for discussions of Google's (and Yahoo's, and...) algorithms. But _only_ after simpler techniques have shown not to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, the loading of data takes all that time because you're dealing with I/O, mirroring the *inflated* strings to hard disk. This will definitely be a bottleneck, mainly depending on the way you read and write data to the disk.

A possible improvement on execution time may be achieved using `mmap` with some LRU policy. I'm quite sure the idea of replicating data is to make the search faster, but since you're using -- as it seems to be -- only one machine, you're bottleneck will go dive from memory searching to I/O requests.

Another solution, which you may not be interested in -- it's sickly funny and disturbing as well (: --, is to split the data among multiple machines. Considering the way you've structured the data, the implementation itself may take a bit of time, but it would be very straightforward. You'd have:

- each machine gets responsible by a set buckets, chosen using something close to `hash_id(bucket) % num_machines`;
- insertions are performed locally, from each machine;
- searches may be either interfaced by some *type your query*-application, or simply clustered into sets of queries -- if the application is not interative;
- searches may even have the interface distributed, considering you may send start a request from a node, and forward requests to another node (also clustered requests, to avoid excessive I/O overhead).

Another good point is that, as you said, data is evenly distributed -- ALREADY \o/; this is usually one of the pickiest parts of a distributed implementation. Besides, this would be highly scalable, as you may add another machine whenever data grows in size.

Comment: I investigated mmap and it's still an option. The search process is wicked fast. Linux caches the disk blocks using its own method which I don't think I could improve on. However, when I write the index items out I run into obvious IO bottlenecks. I'm not sure where the IO bottleneck is exactly because it will do 120 adds in a second and then pause for up to 5 seconds (I assume that is the commit to disk phase). That's why I'm looking for perhaps a better method. I'm not sure multiple machines is the answer.

Comment: Splitting the huge data among multiple machines and handling it in parallel is exactly what can solve the problem

Comment: Maybe. However on the search end I think I would have the added overhead of the network which would increase search times. This may not necessarily be a huge overhead, I'll have to set up some test cases. It would most likely decrease the load time for keys (good) but the trade-off would be slower searches (not so good).

Comment: @mlewis54 Not necessarily; of course you'd have the extra network cost, but you'd either reduce it by the fact that your application may be interative -- user takes time to think of what to look for --, or by the fact that requests would be clustered into sets of requests.

Comment: @mlewis54 - And this is when you will need a cluster manager and whole new technique of "Big data".

Comment: Users are doing searches such as "apple" && "orange" but not "oranges" (expressed as "apple +orange !oranges". You're correct that they will then think about it. I could ship the "string" to be added to each machine and let the individual machines worry about only adding what they control to their local indexes. This might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing everything in one pass, solve the problem in 38 passes.

Read each of the 180,000 strings.  Find "A"s in each string, and write out stuff only to the "A" hash table.  After you are done, write the entire finished result of the "A" hash table out to disk.  (have enough RAM to store the entire "A" hash table in memory -- if you don't, make smaller hash tables.  Ie, have 38^2 hash tables on pairs of starting letters, and have 1444 different tables.  You could even dynamically change how many letters the hash tables are keyed off of have based on how common a prefix they are, so they are all of modest size.  Keeping track of how long such prefixes are isn't expensive.)

Then read each of the 180,000 strings, looking for "B".  Etc.

My theory is that you are going slower than you could because of thrashing of your cache of your massive tables.

The next thing that might help is to limit how long the strings are you do a hash on, in order to shrink the size of your tables.

Instead of doing all 2278 substrings of length 3 to 70 of a string of length 70, if you limited the length of the hash to 10 characters there are only 508 substrings of length 3 to 10.  And there may not be that many collisions on strings of length longer than 10.  You could, again, have the length of the hashes be dynamic -- the length X hash might have a flag for "try a length X+Y hash if your string is longer than X, this is too common", and otherwise simply terminate the hashing.  That could reduce the amount of data in your tables, at the cost of slower lookup in some cases.

Comment: this is something to think about seriously (batch processing). I need to do all the substrings because I need to search for every possible one. I have a very efficient dup key handler for that reason. My typical starting string is usually under 16 characters. I just have to handle the occasional long strings.